# Error LNK1104 cannot open file .lib in a unit test project of a .dll project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I created C++ Dynamic Linked Library project, then I created Native Unit Test project. When I try to run a default empty test, I get the error:
[image]

There is no .lib in the folder:
[image]

Here's a barebones solution with the problem: https://github.com/KulaGGin/TestLibrary

Comment: .dll files still have .lib files for linking.

Comment: ***There is no .lib because it's a dll.*** This is incorrect. There is a `.lib` created for a native `dll` if you actually export a symbol.

Comment: @ChrisMM Not in my case, here's the folder, it isn't there: https://i.imgur.com/Ohc7Xdp.png

Comment: Your code probably does not export a symbol. Did you use a macro that changes between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on if you are building the dll or using it?

Comment: Did you compile "TestLibrary"

Comment: @drescherjm No. I'm new to this. I don't know what macro I am suppose to use.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch)

Comment: @ChrisMM I build the solution.

Comment: Do I need to dllexport my methods to unit test them?

Comment: You likely need to export your methods for native `c++` to call the method from code that is not the dll itself. So yes.

Comment: What if I want to unit test not exported methods? Is there a framework for that? I'm reading different Stackoverflow questions, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496912/unit-testing-non-exported-classes-in-a-dll . But all of them are hacks and have drawbacks: long build times, polluting main project with test files, etc.

Comment: No sure why you want a dll with no exports (I have never wanted to do that in the 25+ years I have been a native c++ windows developer) however maybe you want to compile the same code as a static library so you don't have to export anything.